Konsole | How do I make a .json or a .sh file to open a tab with three terminals with root privileges?
I'm working with docker lately, and everything (or almost) you do in docker needs root privileges, and I end up always with the same layout in my Konsole:
docker commands | docker logs
          docker stats

I have Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, I'm using KDE Plasma and I've installed the Kubuntu default packages (I'm not sure, but even though initially it was an Ubuntu installation, I think that now effectively I have Kubuntu installed), and the Konsole version is 21.12.3.
I found out recently that you can create a .json file specifying a Konsole layout, and I haven't found much info about the options of the file, but even if I knew how to specify the order "sudo -i command /bin/zsh", I would need to introduce my password three times, and that doesn't seem like an optimal solution. I've also seen that Konsole, if it is initiated by command line, it has options, but it didn't seem that the options were powerful enough to hande it through a .sh file. So my question is:
Is there a way to create the a file (.sh or .json) with the specified layout (2+1), with root privileges, introducing the password only once (or 0 times)?

Add your user to docker group either via usermod or directly in /etc/group, then you don't need root permissions
maybe screen or tmux is what you are looking for

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
